# How to tell FNH to map snake-case db columns to Pascal case properties?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate-mapping

We have  convention to turn snake-case db columns to pascal case in our entities:

```
        Map(x => x.ProjectName).Column("project_name");
```

The mapping is always exactly this.  How can we tell FNH to do the work rather than typing them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement `IPropertyConvention` and use

```
// in Apply (maybe filter out some special cases)
instance.Column(ToSnakeCase(instance.Name));


private string ToSnakeCase(string name)
{
    var result = new Stringbuilder(name.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0 && char.IsUpper(name[i]))
            result.Append('_').Append(char.ToLower(name[i]));
        else
            result.Append(char.ToLower(name[i]));
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```